# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am rewriting MySQL statements to prepared ones, because of the SQL injections, but I can't get this to work. It returns:

> Error: 1
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1

```
$cihc = mysqli_prepare($conn,"UPDATE user SET picture=? WHERE id1=?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($cihc, "si", $image, $userid);
$sql = mysqli_stmt_execute($cihc);
mysqli_stmt_close($cihc);
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Sent successfully";
} 
else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

Comment: It would be useful if we could see what the final query looks like, as well as what the values for $image and $userid are.

Comment: $image is just a link and $userid is something like this 111111111111111111111

Comment: @user3783243 Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to execute a query on the result of the `update`. Remove the `query()` call and change the `$sql` assignment, since it isn't actually SQL.

```
$cihc = mysqli_prepare($conn,"UPDATE user SET picture=? WHERE id1=?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($cihc, "si", $image, $userid);
$result = mysqli_stmt_execute($cihc);
mysqli_stmt_close($cihc);
if ($result) {
      echo "Sent successfully";
} else {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```